# Formatting elements from array into a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, yield, enumerable

If I have an array like this:

```
array = ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]
```

And I would like to use the elements of the array to build a sentence.
Like for example "I would like to have an APPLE"

I think I saw something similar being done using the yield method.
But not sure how to use that in this scenario.

If I just parse the array to string like this:

```
the_word = array.to_s
```

Its still is displayed as a array of strings. ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]

So my question is how do I get the elements of the array and formats the elements into a string,
without  iterating the whole sentence multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join()`:

```
1.9.3-p547 :001 > array = ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]
 => ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"] 
1.9.3-p547 :002 > array.join()
 => "APPLE"
```

Or use it without parenthesis (kudos to Anthony's comment):

```
1.9.3-p547 :003 > array.join
 => "APPLE"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, theres alot of handy methods in ruby.

Comment: Being able to `join` an array's elements into a string, using some sort of delimiter or an empty string, is a standard method or function in every language I've ever used, except assembler. So, it's not Ruby that's convenient, it's really the years of language implementors who saw the same need.

Comment: Yes you're right, but Ruby seem to do the same task but with less code compared to Java.

Comment: You can just do `array.join`   (without the parens - it assumes you want to join with nothing between the elements)

Answer (score 2):

There is another method [`Array#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2A), called ***Repetition*** — With a `String` argument, equivalent to `ary.join(str)`.

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> pry
[1] pry(main)> array = ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]
=> ["A", "P", "P", "L", "E"]
[2] pry(main)> array * ""
=> "APPLE"
[3] pry(main)>
```